# I am not able to send JWT token in headers in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, axios, jwt

I am trying to send the `JWT` token in the headers in the `Axios` API call but in react.js I am not able to send it. I have tried some ways to send it in the header but on the backend, I am not able to get it. And If send the same token on `postman` then the backend is able to extract the token from the headers.

```
 const token = window.localStorage.getItem("token");
console.log("token",token) // token

const apiHeaders = {
          headers: {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
            "Content-Type": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
            "token": `${token}`,
          },
        };
        const result = await Axios.get(
          `${process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL}/api/student/AllProjects`,
          {
            withCredentials: true,
            headers: apiHeaders, 
          }
        );
```

I have also tried sending token as

```
 token: `${token}`
or

 token: token
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-*` are **response** headers that come from the server. They do not belong in your request and in general will more than likely result in errors like _"Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers"_.

Comment: So, should I remove this?

Comment: Remove all the headers other than `token`

Comment: Also, content type?

Comment: _**All other than `token`**_. It's unlikely that you're using cookie based authentication in combination with a JWT so you probably don't need `withCredentials` either. And finally, you have an unexpected `.` after `console.log()` that shouldn't be there

Comment: Tried. Still same issue.

Comment: I am getting undefined `const token = req.header("token")` in token. But if I try to call API from the postman and send the token in the header then it's working fine.

Comment: You have a **typo** where you have nested `header` properties. Simply use `Axios.get(\`${process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL}/api/student/AllProjects\`, { headers: { token } })`

Comment: Maybe you can take look here `https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-http-get-request-examples-axios?file=App%2FGetRequestSetHeaders.jsx`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that you have `headers` twice:

```
const apiHeaders = { headers: { ... } }
```

So apiHeaders is an object with a `headers` field.

When you use that in the `get` call, that gets expanded to what is effectively:

```
const result = await Axios.get(
          `${process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL}/api/student/AllProjects`,
          {
            // You probably don't need to do this! withCredentials: true,
            headers: {
               headers: {
                 token: token
               }
            }, 
          }
        );
```

BTW, it would be normal to pass that as a "bearer token" in the authorization header:

```
headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
}
```

Also, you probably don't need the `withCredentials` when you post the token in a header.

Comment: `withCredentials` + a JWT just doesn't make sense. Also, this can be closed as a **typo**

Comment: Yeah you are right. I just copied the original code to exemplify the double headers object

Comment: @Pete Yes, Now it's working fine. You are right I have headers twice and that was the problem.